# Integrate RF3.3 and Trinidad in JSF project

Tags: jsf, jboss, richfaces, integration, trinidad

My web application is running JSF(2.0) without facelets and RF3.3. I need to integrate Trinidad into the existing web application project.

I have downloaded the trinidad jars and have placed them inside WEB-INF/lib folder. However when I went through the configuration guide of Trinidad, i observed I need to add multiple entries in web.xml. Also need to create trinidad-config.xml file..

I am completely lost as I am afraid doing modification in web.xml especially servlets will cause the application to stop responding.

Can anyone please guide how to integrate Trinidad+RF3.3 in JSF(2.0) without facelets.

When I added the jars in WEB-INF/lib and made entry in web.xml and faces-config.xml and started my application I got the following error:

```
16:34:56,895 ERROR [[Faces Servlet]] Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.core.xhtml.FormRenderer.encodeEnd(FormRenderer.java:277)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.render.CoreRenderer.encodeEnd(CoreRenderer.java:515)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.renderkit.htmlBasic.HtmlFormRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlFormRenderer.java:64)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:878)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:295)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:287)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:292)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
        at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChild(RendererBase.java:277)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.renderChildren(RendererBase.java:258)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PageRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PageRenderer.java:265)
        at org.richfaces.renderkit.html.PageRenderer.doEncodeChildren(PageRenderer.java:254)
        at org.ajax4jsf.renderkit.RendererBase.encodeChildren(RendererBase.java:120)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
        at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.doRenderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:420)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:209)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:354)
        at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
        at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:273)
        at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:165)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:100)
        at org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler.renderView(AjaxViewHandler.java:176)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:109)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:601)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
16:34:57,129 ERROR [STDERR] Apr 29, 2013 4:34:57 PM org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewHandlerImpl renderView
WARNING: Trinidad's ViewHandler is registered more than once. To avoid initialization problems, make sure that only one Trinidad implementation jar is loaded
```

Please note the following in web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<!-- This cannot be configured currently -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resources</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adf/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <!-- This assumes that the FacesServlet has been registered -->
    <!-- under the name "faces" -->
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>
```

and

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet> 
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Exist in the web.xml. Please guide.

Comment: I know nothing about Trinidad so I don't want to answer, but it seems that the Trinidad `filter-mapping` element is pointing to a `servlet-name` that doesn't exist.  You are referencing servlet name `faces` when the Faces servlet has a name in `web.xml` as `Faces Servlet`.  Try changing this to `Faces Servlet` and see if that helps.